# Мисс Вселенная / мисс Вселенная

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

`Её все принимают как мисс Вселенную.`

`Её все принимают как Мисс Вселенную.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно:  *Её все принимают как **мисс Вселенную.***

Слово "мисс" в данном предложении **нарицательное** существительное.

***"Мисс Вселенная"*** — название конкурса красоты, там  **первое** слово пишется с прописной буквы.

Comment: И кавычки нужны при конкурсе?

Comment: Да, нужны, это та тема, где обычно используются кавычки. «Мисс Вселенная» (англ. Miss Universe) — ежегодный международный конкурс красоты. Один из самых престижных конкурсов красоты в мире, входит в «Большую четвёрку» наряду с конкурсами «Мисс мира», «Мисс Интернешнл» и «Мисс Земля».

Comment: А вот песенка: Стала обалденная, прямо (= как) Мисс Вселенная! Кавычек нет, но мисс с прописной буквы.